# Release/dispose of a UIViewController in MonoTouch

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, didreceivememorywarning

As I understand it, we need to hold references to our Cocoa objects when dealing with them in MonoTouch. The reason for this is that the ObjC runtime might still hold references to the objects, and if we have no "MonoTouch references" on them, they could be garbage collected, which results in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` as soon as the ObjC runtime tries to access them.

Say, we have two UIViewController subclasses, VC1 and VC2. If the user clicks on a button on VC1, the UI navigates to VC2, and the user can navigate back and forth. If I create a new instance of VC2 every time the user navigates to it, then the references to the old instances get lost, so they're garbage collected and the app crashes the next time a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is propagated to the UIViewControllers.

How can I release the old references, so I don't have to use the same instance of VC2 every time? `Dispose` seemed to not be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As I understand it, we need to hold references to our Cocoa objects when dealing with them in MonoTouch.

Not quite. MonoTouch **managed** instances will keep a reference to **native** instances. As long as the **managed** instance exists the **native** instance will be alive (since they are reference counted and MonoTouch won't release it's reference).

IOW your need to hold references to the MonoTouch **managed** instances as long as their **native** part are required.

> The reason for this is that the ObjC runtime might still hold references to the objects ... they could be garbage collected,

Native (Objective C) instances are reference counted, not garbage collected. Native instances won't be released until their *reference count* reach 0 (which won't happen while an associated **managed** instance exists);

Also native instances can hold references to other native instances. Not every *native* instances have a corresponding *managed* instance.

> which results in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS as soon as the ObjC runtime tries to access them.

That won't happen, at least not this way. OTOH it's hard to tell you what's happening in your case (without seeing the code and/or the crashes).

I **suspect** you're disposing (manually or not) your **managed** instances before they have completed their jobs. Here's a *simplified* of what could happen:

- you create a *managed* MT.X instance (e.g. an `UIView`);
- this creates and reference a *native* X (native reference count == 1);
- you override an event (or add a delegate...) `ViewWillUnload' on MT.X (which also exists natively);
- you assign the MT.X instance to another (managed) instance, e.g. an `UIViewController`;
- the **native** `UIViewController` will add a reference to the **native** X (native reference count == 2);
- application executes happilly...
- you stop having a reference to the `MT.X` instance (e.g. set the variable to `null` or a different instance);
- since there's no reference to `MT.X` anymore the Garbage Collector will dispose the **managed** instance, calling `Dispose` which will **reduce** the reference to *native* X (native reference count == 1). But the *native* instance won't be freed since it's still referenced (not 0) by the view controller;
- the `UIViewController` does something that triggers, natively, `X.ViewWillUnload` (e.g. it tries to load a new `UIView`);
- since `X` still exists natively (ref count == 1) it will call it's `ViewWillUnload` which will try to go back to the **managed** instance... that was **disposed**.

The solution to this problem is to ensure ensure you're not disposing **managed** instance until their **native** part have completed their jobs.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm sure I don't have any references left. The only managed thing that references `VC2` is my `VC1` instance, so when I'm nulling this instance, the reference count on the native `VC2` instance should be 0. But it seems like iOS is keeping a reference to the controller for the distribution of `didReceiveMemoryWarning` messages, because as soon as there is a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` message, my app crashes.

Comment: You likely don't have **managed** references but you could well have **native** references left (between them or their parent). You should not null them (managed side) before you're sure their life cycle (native side) is over since it could call back into a disposed (managed) instance. If you have (or can extract) a small test case then open a bug report @ http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and we'll review the code.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to isolate it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sebastien, is it possible to determine which selector system tried to call from sigsegv crash log?

Comment: @chebum not right now (the native stack is not visible) but it's something that's being worked on

Answer (score 1):

I've the same situation in my app and GC collects objects correctly. In other words, I never experienced a problem simply nulling reference to a VC and letting GC do the rest.

However, I DID have problems when called for `Dispose` method as you do. It seems we shouldn't do this manually. Instead we should wait for GC to collect objects and free its resources. Base `NSObject` class has a call to `Dispose` in its finalizer, so all unmanaged resources will be freed upon object is collected.

You may also call for `GC.Collect` in some of the root VC's `DidReceiveMemoryWarning` method.